# OSError:[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket -Python-socket-opencv

Tags: python, sockets

This Python code for open camera and detect blue color then power on led esp if sends 'R'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils
import socket               

sock = socket.socket()

host = "192.168.4.1"  #ESP32 IP in local network
port = 80             #ESP32 Server Port    

def tr(s):
    if s=='L':
        sock.connect((host, port))
        sock.send(s.encode('utf-8'))
        sock.close()
    
    elif s=='R':
        sock.connect((host, port))
        sock.send(s.encode('utf-8'))
        sock.close()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    _,frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_blue = np.array([90,60,0])
    upper_blue = np.array([121,255,255])

    mask4 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue,upper_blue)

    cnts4 = cv2.findContours(mask4, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts4 = imutils.grab_contours(cnts4)



    for c in cnts4:
        area4 = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area4 > 5000 and area4 < 50000:
            cv2.drawContours(frame, [c],-1,(0,255,0),3)
        
       
            tr('R')
        
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            cx = int(M["m10"]/M["m00"])
            cy = int(M["m01"]/M["m00"])
        
            cv2.circle(frame, (cx,cy),7,(255,255,255),-1)
            cv2.putText(frame,"Blue",(cx-20,cy-20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,2.5,(255,255,255),1)
        
        
    cv2.imshow("result",frame)




    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xff == 'q':
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Suleiman/Desktop/newnewnewnewnewenw/classifier/colorNEW.py', wdir='C:/Users/Suleiman/Desktop/newnewnewnewnewenw/classifier')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Suleiman\Desktop\newnewnewnewnewenw\classifier\colorNEW.py", line 122, in <module>
    tr('R')

  File "C:\Users\Suleiman\Desktop\newnewnewnewnewenw\classifier\colorNEW.py", line 29, in tr
    sock.connect((host, port))

OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with `socket` only, not with OpenCV, numpy, etc. Get rid of all the irrelevant code, and provide a proper [mcve]. I wouldn't be surprised if you could fit everything relevant in 10 lines of code tops.

Comment: You can’t reuse a closed socket. Make a new one each time